# Laravel authorization throws an error when being used in blade template

Tags: php, laravel

The UrlGenerator is throwing an exception

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 337:

Action App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@view not defined.
```

I have a code like this in my blade product view

```
@can('view', App\Product::class)
    <a href="{{ action('ProductController@show', 1) }}">Product View</a>
@endcan
```

So in my ProductPolicy

```
public function view(User $user, Product $product)
{
    return true;
}
```

I registered the product policy in my AuthServiceProvider class

```
protected $policies = [
     Product::class => ProductPolicy::class
];
```

Comment: Please show your `ProductController` and `web.php`

Comment: I'm using the resource `Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');`

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter passed to action method must be an array [Read More](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-action).

It Should be like

```
  <a href="{{ action('ProductController@show', ['id' => 1]) }}">Product View</a>
```

Comment: From this api here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L62 the second parameter don't need to be an array because the method will wrap it in an array if its not an array.